# start a program if it is not started, close the program if it is started

Tags: batch-file

you can start a program only if it is started? All this from a batch file.
Also you can close if you started? From the same file.

```
@echo off
tasklist /fi "patch and program.exe" > nul
if errorlevel 1 start program
```

How can I continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to start a service:

```
SC START SERVICENAME
```

Here is how to stop a service:

```
SC STOP SERVICENAME
```

Here is how to check if a service is running or not:

```
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a IN (
    'wmic service get name^,state /format:TABLE ^| findstr /i /r /c:"SERVICENAME"') DO (
    IF %%a==Stopped (
        SC START SERVICENAME
    )
    IF %%a==Running (
        SC STOP SERVICENAME
    )
)
```

The last piece of code will start the service if it is stopped and stop it if it is running.

EDIT:

If you want to do this with a task instead of a service, here is the code:

```
@echo off
tasklist|findstr something.exe
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 taskkill /IM something.exe
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 call something.exe
```

There are several ways to achieve this. This is one of them. Another one would be this:

```
@echo off
taskkill /im something.exe
if %errorlevel%=128 call something.exe
```

This code will first try to kill the task. If it is running, it will be killed with `%errorlevel% 0` so the **if** statement will be ignored. If the task is not running, the `taskkill` command will terminate with `%errorlevel% 128` which means that no such task was found. So the **if** statement will be executed and `call something.exe` will start the program.

Comment: does not work, it's a program, you can use tasklist / fi?

Comment: The title of your questions tells me that it's about services. Services != programs. Please edit your post and clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @MarioChiuri I've updated my answer. Check the EDIT section.

Comment: It works perfectly now, but I want the command prompt can not remain open, you can? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is this code snipet part of a bigger bat file and you want to terminate the cmd after this part? Usually `exit` is the command to terminate the comsole window. How you use it depends on the rest of your code. Sometimes you can just append an `exit` line at the end of your code, sometimes you will have to append `&exit` or `&&exit` to your code lines.

Comment: I mean that when launching the bat file should not show the window of the command prompt.
If you launch the batch file, remains opened the command prompt and does not close as expected